# Laravel Model Factories - ошибка

Tags: php, laravel, composer

Хочу заполнить тестовыми данными с помощью

```
php artisan tinker
```

и затем

```
factory(App\Product::class, 100)→create();
```

Показывает ошибку:
**PHP Parse error: Syntax error, unexpected T_STRING on line 1**
В чём может причина ?

Comment: Символ стрелки кривой какой то

Comment: Спасибо, помогло )